# Using Python to calculate aggregate values from a Json file

Tags: python, arrays, json

I do manual calculations from a json file and import the data. I want to automate the process using python. I am looking to pick few values based on the json file do the calculation. Below is the sample Json file so in order to calculate a SayDo formula, i have to take the sum(completed story points)/sum(committed story points) based on director. In this case director "Rajesh." Could you please point me to the right source

#### Sample Data Set

```
{"saydo": [{"teamName": "EPAM Backend 1", "sprintName": "MF-S94", "director": "Rajesh", "location": "Ukraine",
            "vendors": "EPAM,FTE", "sayDo": 77, "saydoStatusMeassure": "Yellow", "saydoStatusMeassureNumber": 0,
            "commitedSayDo": 68, "commitedSaydoStatusMeassure": "Yellow", "commitedSaydoStatusMeassureNumber": 0,
            "commitedStories": 17, "completedStories": 16, "completedStoryPoints": 56, "commitedStoryPoints": 73,
            "completedSoryPointsWithoutAddedAfterSprintStart": 50, "incompletedStories": 5,
            "addedAfterSprintStartStories": 5, "removedStories": 1, "bugsPerDev": 0.75,
            "bugsStatusMeassureNumber": 0, "bugsStatusMeassure": "Yellow", "openBeforeSprintEndsBugs": 6,
            "membersCount": 12, "completedBugsCount": 9, "p3BugsStatusMeassureNumber": 1,
            "p3BugsStatusMeassure": "Green", "p3BugsCount": 1, "addedIssuesAfterSprintCount": 6,
            "completedInSprintCount": 9, "techDebtIsuuesCount": 3, "foundAndFixedBugsValue": 100,
            "foundAndFixedBugsStatusMeassureNumber": 1, "foundAndFixedBugsStatusMeassure": "Green",
            "afterProdStatusMeassureNumber": 1, "afterProdStatusMeassure": "Green", "bugsAfterProdCount": 0}]}
```

My code so far is

```
import json

def test3():
with open('C:/Users/erpsaam/Desktop/say-do-statistics-MF-S82-MF-S94-2018-07-09--10-30.json') as f:
           d = json.load(f)
   print (d['saydo'][1]['director'])

test3()
```

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverFlow. Can you please format both your sample Data Set and your code properly? so we can be of more help.

Comment: Could you post your wanted result?

Comment: Below is the data set

Answer (score 0):

1. Your input format is weird: I don't see the point for having 
   a dictionary for one list of one dictionary...
2. I would do something like this:

   import pandas as pd

   d=pd.read_json('toto.json') # replace 'toto.json' by your json file.
   df=pd.DataFrame([d['saydo'][0]]) # convert this awkward format into a regular pandas dataframe

   (df.completedStoryPoints/df.commitedStoryPoints)[df.director=='Rajesh']
3. not sure to fully understand the question: what do you mean by 'right source' ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try use Pandas see [read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html). There are a lot of aggregation functions.